# How to pass data to ALL reducers or call all actions as a components need data onload. Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

My app has one store with multiple reducers as it is a single page app so each "page" has its own reducers. Problem is, I am creating a redis api so that a user can "save" state. When a user refreshes, I need to ping redis and there is data, funnel it thru the reducers to now update the state.

So, if I have a few reducers to manage different parts of the store, what is the best way or even how, and where ( parent component ) to bring in this redis data and then push it thru the reducers, my guess is that I would have to call the actions - as then they would call the reducers..

```
/actions
----> productsActions
----> userDataActions
----> deliveryActions

/reducers
----> productsReducer
----> userDataReucer
----> deliveryReducer

Application
---> Routes 
------> Child Routes for products/data/delivery
```

When a user refreshes, my store is gone. I want now retrieve that data and update the store/state all in one fell swoop, as I have a cart that when opened shows all the data, and that is a seperate component.

I hope I explained succinctly. I am really just having a hard time grasping how this would be done.

edit: ok, so - I am thinking each reducer has its own "default" state, perhaps on page load, grab the redis data and update theses default states. This way I do not have to call the actions?

edite 2: If that is the case, is there a redux api that handles conditions in which fetching the data takes longer than the page to load, which case I would need the reducers to be instantiated again so they pick up the "new default states"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to rehydrate your stores. You might want to check out [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) as it does most of what I think you want.